# SOAP API with DomainBox in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, soap

I am trying to integrate an ASP.NET application to http://www.domainbox.com/ using their SOAP API. I couldn't find any examples. The only thing they offer is the SOAP Resquest and Response examples. My question is how do I call the request and how to I get the response data to use in my application?

---

REQUEST:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” xmlns:soap12=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/
soap-envelope”>
<soap12:Body>
<QueryDomainRenewalSettings xmlns=”https://sandbox.domainbox.net/”>
<AuthenticationParameters>
<Reseller>myreseller</Reseller>
<Username>myusername</Username>
<Passwordmy>password</Password>
</AuthenticationParameters>
<CommandParameters>
<DomainName>atestdomain.co</DomainName>
</CommandParameters>
</QueryDomainRenewalSettings>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

---

RESPONSE:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope”
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xmlns:xsd=”http://www.
w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”>
<soap:Body>
<QueryDomainRenewalSettingsResponse xmlns=”https://sandbox.domainbox.net/”>
<QueryDomainRenewalSettingsResult>
<ResultCode>100</ResultCode>
<ResultMsg>Domain Renewal Settings Queried Successfully</ResultMsg>
<TxID>4d76201a-3b6d-4ccc-bca5-729439bbac9b</TxID>
<DomainId>87967</DomainId>
<AutoRenew>true</AutoRenew>
<AutoRenewDays>60</AutoRenewDays>
</QueryDomainRenewalSettingsResult>
</QueryDomainRenewalSettingsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Domainbox API as a service reference if you're using ASP.NET.

That will let you use it just like a normal C#/VB class,

```
var parameters = new Domainbox.CheckDomainAvailabilityParameters {DomainName= "example.com"};
var result = apiObject.CheckDomainAvailiability(authObject, paramters);
if (result.ResultCode == 100) { // get results... }
```

I can provide more detailed example if required.

Comment: i just started with domain box and would like to see some more examples.  I added the sandbox.domainbox.net web reference

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out with the commands.  Here is question though.  Are you using the services directly in your application or did you put a wrapper around them to only expose ur own methods?  if so what was ur approach?

Comment: @ChampChris I generally access the service reference methods directly.

Comment: oh ok.  I was wrapping in the wrapper separated from my my project.